# Performance issues with data.table v1.13.0 in a repeated loop

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, data.table

I have seen a huge performance drop in data.table loop operations, possibly due to the new version upgrade

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

dt <- data.table('id'=1:20000,
                 'list_col'=sample(c('', '', 'a', 'a:b', 'a:b:c'), 20000, TRUE))
feature <- 'list_col'

microbenchmark(
  long_dt <- dt[, c("id", feature), with = FALSE][
    , feature_names := {
      x <- get(feature)
      stringr::str_split(x, ':')
    }][
      , .(
        feature_names = paste0(feature, "_", unlist(feature_names))
      )
      , by = "id"]
  , times = 10
  , unit = 'ms'
)
```

data.table 1.12.8, default settings, using 6 threads:

```
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 122.2447 149.6991 173.3268 183.5777 193.9876 201.7234    10
```

data.table 1.13.0, default settings,  using 6 threads:

```
      min      lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
 12820.75 12913.1 12989.59 13007.94 13065.1 13097.85    10
```

This might be related to the new throttle feature (see: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md)

Also, I have tried several different `threads` and `throttle` combinations, but have seen no improvements at all

Comment: That NEWS entry suggested setting `setDTthreads(throttle=1)` to get the previous behavior, and other values based on your data and such. Have you tried that yet? Since they end that entry with *"We welcome feedback and test results indicating what the best default should be"*, I'm not surprised there are unintended slow-downs in some workflows (I haven't tested mine yet), it might be appropriate to put this discussion as an issue there.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I have tested that already, and couldn't get any improvements

Comment: Even more likely then that this needs to be addressed within the `data.table` devs as an issue there. (I'm not saying you can't/won't get help here, but ... help *here* may patch the symptom, an issue *there* may change (fix?) the behavior of the package itself.)

Comment: This seems to be due to excessive garbage collection, according to the output of `profvis`. Would be interesting to also profile version 1.12.8...

Comment: Could we see your `sessionInfo()`?